# How do i convert the value of a timer event to a number?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I'm making a game where the reaction time to killing an enemy is shown and used in later calculations. The number needs to be precise and in seconds, with three significant figures. So i need the current value of a timer to be converted to a numerical value.

I have it so the enemy spawns, a timer (reactionTimer) event begins and when it's killed a variable (reactionTime) will be set to the reactionTimer.

a new one then spawns and it resets the timer and variable.

I've had a few tries at it but it always ends up showing the timer value as either "Object Timer" or 0.

I've also tried using `currentCount` but this doesn't give me decimal numbers and just works oddly.

Answer (score 3):

New ActionScript developers often mix up the purpose of the [`Timer` class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) and `TimerEvent`. It's really for triggering actions at a specific time, not for *measuring* time.

For measuring time, you use the [`getTimer` function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29). Whenever you call it, it returns the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since Flash player started. To measure an elapsed time you just call `getTimer()` twice and subtract the first measurement from the second.

There are a lot of ways you could organize your particular situation. One would be to store the spawn timestamp of the enemy right on the enemy class, capturing it the constructor:

```
public class Enemy extends MovieClip {
    public function get spawnTime():int { return _spawnTime; }
    private var _spawnTime:int;

    // Constructor
    public function Enemy() {
        super();
        _spawnTime = getTimer();
    }
}
```

Then when enemy is killed you call `getTimer()` again to get the reaction time:

```
// Somewhere, where you are processing the enemy killed event
var killTime:int = getTimer();
var reactionTime:int = killTime - killedEnemy.spawnTime; // in whole ms
var reactionSeconds:Number = reactionTime / 1000;        // in seconds
```